# GDB reports wrong address for parameter in c++ object's constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, gdb, parameter-passing, stdstring

I'm experiencing a weird behavior with GDB passing a string as the parameter to a constructor.
The code works fine, but when I step through in the debugger, GDB seems to think my parameter is at a different address then it is. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Here's the simplest program I can create that demonstrates the problem:

```
--(jwcacces@neptune)--------------------------------------------(/home/jwcacces)--
--$ nl gdb_weird.cpp
     1  #include <iostream>
     2  #include <string>
     3
     4  class C
     5  {
     6  public:
     7     C(std::string str)
     8     {
     9        std::string* str_ptr = &str;
    10        std::cout << "Address of str: " << &str << std::endl;
    11        std::cout << "Address in str_ptr: " << str_ptr << std::endl;
    12        std::cout << "Value of str: " << str << std::endl;
    13     };
    14  };
    15
    16  int main(int, char*[])
    17  {
    18     std::string s("Hello, World!");
    19     C c(s);
    20     return 0;
    21  }
```

Compile with debugging info, no optimization.
Note, that I see this problem when compiled for x86, x64, and mingw(x86).
I have not tried other architectures.

```
--(jwcacces@neptune)--------------------------------------------(/home/jwcacces)--
--$ g++ -O0 -g -Wall -Wextra gdb_weird.cpp -m32

--(jwcacces@neptune)--------------------------------------------(/home/jwcacces)--
--$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Now, debug:

```
--(jwcacces@neptune)--------------------------------------------(/home/jwcacces)--
--$ gdb a.out
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.3-0ubuntu2) 7.3-2011.08
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/jwcacces/a.out...done.

(gdb) br main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80488ce: file gdb_weird.cpp, line 18.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jwcacces/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at gdb_weird.cpp:18
18         std::string s("Hello, World!");

(gdb) next
19         C c(s);

(gdb) step
C::C (this=0xffffd74f, str=...) at gdb_weird.cpp:9
9             std::string* str_ptr = &str;
```

Here's the weirdness, when I try to output `str`, I get garbage:

```
(gdb) output str
{
  static npos = <optimized out>,
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>},
                                           <No data fields>},
                 _M_p = 0xffffd748 "\024\260\004\b\364\177\354\367\360\211\004\b\364\177\354", <incomplete sequence \367>
                }
}
```

So, what does GDB think the address of `str` is?

```
(gdb) output &str
(std::string *) 0xffffd734
```

And what does the program think the address of `str` is?

```
(gdb) next
10            std::cout << "Address of str: " << &str << std::endl;

(gdb) next
Address of str: 0xffffd748
11            std::cout << "Address in str_ptr: " << str_ptr << std::endl;

(gdb) next
Address in str_ptr: 0xffffd748
12            std::cout << "Value of str: " << str << std::endl;
```

This is really strange, the program thinks `str` is at `0xffffd748`, but gdb thinks its at `0xffffd734`
And, when you output the string object that would be at `0xffffd748` it works correctly.

```
(gdb) output *(std::string*)0xffffd748
{
  static npos = <optimized out>,
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, 
                                           <No data fields>
                                          },
                 _M_p = 0x804b014 "Hello, World!"
                }
}
```

And the program itself hs no problem using the parameter:

```
(gdb) next
Value of str: Hello, World!
13         };

(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 19463) exited normally]

(gdb) quit
```

I have tried changing the type of the constructor parameter to an int, a struct, a pointer, but I can not reproduce the weirdness.
Also, I have tried setting the debugging format to -ggdb.

Questions:

- What's going on here?
- Why does gdb say that `std::string`'s `npos` member is optimized out (optimized out of library maybe), and does that have anything to do with it?
- Is it just a coincidence that in the "object" that would be where GDB thinks `str` is, the `_M_p` member points to `0xffffd748`, the address that `str` actually is located at?
- In what other circumstances with this behavior happen?

---- WOAH, Breakthrough ----
If I set the debugging format to -gstabs+, GDB gets the address of `str` right.
Does this mean that the gdb debugging format does not work correctly?

Comment: What sticks out to me is that your "correct" pointer 0xffffd748 also shows up as the `_M_p` member of the "invalid" string from your first print statement. So perhaps gdb is confused between a pointer-to- and a pointer-to-pointer-to- ? BTW I assume simply saying "this is why you should pass strings as const-refs" isn't an appropriate answer :p

Comment: The string passes fine as a regular parameter (non qualified pass by value), it's just gdb that has a problem with it.

And yeah, the _M_p pointer is really weird to me.

Comment: It must be something to do with the std::string being a function argument - if you assign str to another std::string variable inside C::C() and then examine that second variable in gdb then that looks fine, even though the function argument appears to be junk to gdb.

Comment: It’s a known bug in the gdb bugzilla, but the bug report seems to be moribund since the bug was reported in 2011: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13427

Comment: Might be a gcc bug though - compile the same code with clang++ -gdwarf-4 and gdb will debug it quite happily.

Comment: Hopefully fixed in gcc 9, based on that sourceware link? :)

Answer (score 1):

From any post (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-04/msg01037.html) it seems that -gstabs or -gstabs+ are the correct flags when debugging C++. I hope this can help.